# Prevent line stretching in list environment

Tags: lists, scrbook

I'm using the scrbook class with the default setting to use flushbottom. It seems that Latex like to stretch especially list environments to fill a page. I think a gap between paragrahs would be better than within the list environment. Is it possible to prevent the line stretching within a list environment to a maximum or to define non stretchable boxes of text?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
   \lipsum[1]   
   \lipsum[2]
    \begin{itemize}
        \item First item
        \item Second Item
        \item Third Item
        \item Fourth Item
        \item Fifth Item
    \end{itemize}

    \lipsum[3]  

    \pagebreak

\end{document}
```

Comment: The most common source for overstretching is using `\begin{figure}[H]` (or `table`); are you doing it, by chance?

Comment: @egreg No all my float environments have the tbp option

Comment: Nice to know! The `[H]` option should rarely (read *never*) used. You're being unlucky with indivisible parts, such as section titles and what follows. I suggest not to worry about these problems until at the end, when the text is in its final form, so adjustments to pagination will not be made obsolete by later additions or changes to the text. However, glue stretching is not subject to a maximum: when there is stretchability, it can be used *ad infinitum* if circumstances require it: in other words, if TeX really needs to break a page somewhere, it will stretch as much as it needs.

Comment: @egreg Assume that I'm at the final stage of preparing a printable version. I added a MWE to illustrate my problem (the pagebreak only for illustration). I think it would look better if the stretching would be made between paragraph 1 and 2 or between the end of the list and paragraph 3. Is there no way to define non stretchable blocks of text (in this case paragraph 2 and the list environment)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the stretchability between the items with `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum*[2]
\begin{itemize}[itemsep=1\itemsep,parsep=1\parsep,partopsep=1\partopsep,topsep=1\topsep]
  \item First item
  \item Second Item
  \item Third Item
  \item Fourth Item
  \item Fifth Item
\end{itemize}
\lipsum[3]

\pagebreak

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course in a real application, the stretching between paragraphs will not be as dramatic. If you want that no stretching is applied to the paragraphs breaks before and after the list, you have to enclose the list and the following paragraphs in a group and set `\parskip` to zero in the group:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]   
\lipsum*[2]
\begingroup\parskip=0pt
\begin{itemize}[itemsep=1\itemsep,parsep=1\parsep,partopsep=1\partopsep,topsep=1\topsep]
  \item First item
  \item Second Item
  \item Third Item
  \item Fourth Item
  \item Fifth Item
\end{itemize}
\lipsum[3]  
\endgroup

\pagebreak

\end{document}
```

[image]